# uiview zorder when using CATransform3DMakeRotation

Tags: ios, uitableview, quartz-core

the situation is as follow: the self.view contains:1, a custom bar which is actually a uiview with some buttons on it and its height is 44px
2, a uitable view y-pos starts at 44th px. the rows have 150px tall and wide button. on touching the button, a tmp uiview with similar look to the button added on the table at same position where button is. some animation block happens and uiview covers the whole table and shows some content.

so far all is fine.

now if one scrolls the table up so that bottom half is visible and the top half is invisible.
the tmp view gets added properly at the same location but while using CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) the left half looks on the top of the custom bar even though the tmp view added using insertSubview belowSubview:customBar.
i tried to send the view to back but no luck.
so any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was very easy. the view which should be on the top of all even during flipping should have a large positive zposition value before applying the animation.

```
self.myview.layer.zPosition =200.0f;
```